# How to make Blender recognize RX5700XT

Tags: gpu, opencl

On a factory startup, Blender does not recognize my RX5700XT (RDNA1) even though I'm on 22.40 AMD drivers. (HIP)

Is there documentation on how I should setup blender to get my GPU to work?

**System Information**

```
Operating system: Linux-5.15.0-56-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35 64 Bits
Graphics card: AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT (navi10, LLVM 15.0.3, DRM 3.49, 5.15.0-56-generic) AMD 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.3.0-devel
```

**Blender Version**

```
Broken: version: 3.5.0 Alpha, branch: master, commit date: 2022-11-13 17:24, hash: `rB7419e291e8b8`
```

Comment: Either you don’t have GPU compute set to the right language in Preferences https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/system.html , your GPU is too old and/or isn’t supported https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html , or this is a bug.

Comment: You also didn't state what operating system you have installed, nor what version of Blender you are running, nor what relevant settings in Blender you are using, or how you came to the conclusion Blender is not detecting you GPU

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it is about troubleshooting temporary issues with unfinished, under development or experimental versions of software, which are expected to be working properly upon stable release. These transitory questions are unlikely to be useful in the future, rendering their long term value low, and making them unappealing for a knowledge database site.